# Difference between RSA and pkcs8

Tags: ssl, openssl

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in server.key -out server.der -nocrypt

openssl rsa -inform PEM -in server.key -outform DER -out server2.der
```

I'm trying to find out why server.der and server2.der are two different files? Isn't RSA always pkcs8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -in server.key -outform DER -out server2.der
```

produces the key in [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-3.2) format which is always RSA by definition. PKCS#1 standard defines the syntax for RSA keys specifically.

Command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in server.key -out server.der -nocrypt
```

produces the key in [PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208) format. PKCS#8 standard defines syntax for storing private keys generally. PKCS#8 is not bound to a particular algorithm. PKCS#8 may contain private keys of different algorithms.

PKCS#8 is an abstraction of a higher level in comparison to PKCS#1. When the private key is based on RSA and PKCS#8 is used for storing it, then PKCS#8 contains the PKCS#1 RSA key as well as metadata about it such as the `AlgorithmIdentifier`:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#appendix-A

```
PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
   version Version,
   privateKeyAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier {{PrivateKeyAlgorithms}},
   privateKey PrivateKey,
   attributes [0] Attributes OPTIONAL }
```

If you output the key in both formats (PKCS#1 & PKCS#8) in PEM format instead of DER, and if they are not secret you can compare them on your own using:
http://lapo.it/asn1js/

You will see there that PKCS#8 simply wraps the PKCS#1 key.